# Как задать имя переменной через конкатенацию? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть переменные:

```
user_id = 94358349
config_xxxxxxx = 'test'
```

Как мне вместо xxxxxxx подставить значение переменной user_id, чтобы переменная выглядела вот так:

```
config_94358349 = 'test'
```

Comment: Вам это не нужно. Используйте списки или словари.

Answer (score 2):

Напрямую - никак, но можно сделать dict с нужным ключом и значением:

```py
configs = {}
user_id = "USER ID" # замените своим значением user_id
# теперь можно просто добавить новый ключ со значением в configs
configs["config_" + str(user_id)] = "Данные" # замените "Данные" своим необходимым значением

# Теперь в configs будет находиться нужные значения
print(configs)
```

Потом можно обращаться так:

```py
print(configs["config_" + str(user_id)])
```

Comment: Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: На самом деле, можно и переменную создавать - с помощью globals() или locals(). Но почти всегда стоит предпочесть ваш вариант с отдельным словарём.

Comment: @Xander спасибо! Это полезно знать.